# is it possible to define a default sort order for a sequelize model

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm looking for a way to define a default sort order for a model in sequelize so that records always come back alphabetically sorted on a given field, for example - something like a user model that has a 'name' field, I'd like the users to be sorted alphabetically by default when I do `User.findAll()`.

This question is *NOT* about how to define the sort order in the `findAll` options, I already know how to do that:

```
User.findAll({ order: [['name', 'ASC']] })
```

I want something like the rails default sort order:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order(name: :desc) }
end
```

I have to admit, I haven't read the sequelize docs in detail, which I'm doing now, but if someone can point it out in the meantime

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**

a default scope can be applied to a model, something along these lines:

```
MyGreatModel.addScope('defaultScope', {
  order: [['id', 'ASC']],
}, { override: true })
```

I've found 2 very useful resources to answer my question, first, [the sequelize docs about scopes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/scopes.html)
and I knew to look for this from an answer on [this github issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9289#issuecomment-382566071)